# Maven: Groovy-Eclipse Compiler plugin with Groovy 2.3.5

Tags: java, maven, groovy, maven-3, groovy-eclipse

Since [GMaven](http://gmaven.codehaus.org/) has been discontinued, I have been using [Groovy-Eclipse Compiler plugin](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy-Eclipse+compiler+plugin+for+Maven) on my Maven projects. The version I used is 2.8.0-01 and I specifically used Groovy 2.1. I know 2.9.0-01-SNAPSHOT has been out for the longest time, but there's no ETA when it will be officially released.

My question here is... can I use safely use version 2.8.0-01 with Groovy 2.3.5 without potential side effects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there is no groovy-eclipse-batch 2.3.5 you can not use it with any version of groovy-eclipse-compiler.

Probably there won't be a 2.3.5 of groovy-eclipse-batch ever, since groovy 2.3.6 has already been released. Once the 2.3.6 compiler is ported to greclipse, we will put out a release of the groovy-eclipse-batch artefact to maven central that is compatible with groovy-eclipsec-compiler 2.9.0 (which has recently been released)

Right now, the latest groovy-eclipse-batch you can use is 2.3.4-01 and it is compatible with the released version of groovy-eclipse-compiler 2.9.0-01.

For the latest released artefacts see:

- http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|groovy-eclipse-batch
- http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|groovy-eclipse-compiler

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. Groovy-Eclipse adopts new versions of Groovy. In fact Groovy-Eclipe includes support for various versions of Groovy it supports. For each supported version of Groovy there will be a corresponding feature available from the update site. Groovy-Eclipse 2.9.0 has suppoort for Groovy 2.3.x and you'd have more luck with Groovy 2.3.5 with that version of Groovy-Eclipse. 
There is some sort of a problem with Groovy 2.3.5 release, hence I'd recommend 2.3.6, which should be out now. Groovy-Eclipse support for Groovy 2.3.6 should be in very soon, hence I'd recommend to install Groovy-Eclipse from this update site at the end of the week: http://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.4

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation as you with GMaven, switched to the Groovy-Eclipse, but note that there is a replacement for GMaven now, [GMavenPlus](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVENPLUS/Home), which works very much like the original GMaven, and I've switched back.

I was using 2.1, but wanted to upgrade to 2.3 because there were inconsistencies where groovyc would compile code using @CompileStatic while Groovy-Eclipse would give an error. The Groovy-Eclipse compiler had the advantage that it can compile Java and Groovy without stubs. The main advantage with GMavenPlus is that it compiles with the standard Groovy compiler of any version you want and also supports indy.

If Groovy-Eclipse is more important, the existing answers are all right. If using the version of Groovy you want and frequent upgrades is more important, then consider GMavenPlus.