# Selecting exact Groovy version in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, groovy, configuration

In Eclipse Juno when I try to run Groovy source (that has a `main` method inside of it) I get:

```
Caught: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Conflicting module versions. Module [groovy-all is loaded in version 2.3.4 and you are trying to load version 2.3.3
```

Google, surprisingly, turned up nothing. When I go to `Project >> Properties >> Groovy Compiler` I see that my Groovy compiler is at 2.3, but it doesn't give me the option to select 2.3.3 or 2.3.4.

Any ideas what the fix is?

Comment: Also worth taking a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046380/how-to-change-eclipse-groovy-plugin-groovy-libraries, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998799/maven-groovy-eclipse-compiler-plugin-with-groovy-2-3-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no fix for that. Each groovy-eclipse compiler is a version tweaked to work with eclipse JDT and whatnot. You can try to use other [groovy-eclipse versions](http://dist.springsource.org/), which might feature the groovy version you need

Comment: Thanks @Will P (+1) but I don't even understand what the problem is. Are you saying that the Eclipse-Groovy plugin that I installed is on 2.3.4, and that my project is on Groovy 2.3.3? If so, couldn't I just upgrade change my project to use 2.3.4? If not, why?!? If so, how?!? Thanks again!

Comment: Wait. You have `groovy-all-2.3.3.jar` in your classpath, don't you? I've had this problem when my `groovy-all.jar` was in a different version than `groovy-eclipse`'s own compiler.

Comment: Yes I do, is that the fix (remove it from the classpath?)

Comment: No, use the same as groovy-eclipse